# MySQL & Terminal: Permissions Issue

Tags: linux, terminal, mysqldump

I cannot seem to push information up into my database via Terminal. MySQL logic is proper, and it acts like the dump was successful. However, the data never gets pushed up into the DB. I'm even logged in as root, which has all permissions on the server *and* inside of MySQL.

**(Edit) My command is:**

```
 mysqldump -u root -p DBNAME db_table < /home/MJV/.../.../db_table_backup.sql
```

It gives:

```
-- Dump completed on 2016-07-15 15:22:19
```

Any advice on how to proceed? Thank you!

Edit: Giacomo1968 told me to run the following command:

```
mysql -uroot -p[password] dbname db_table </home/MJV/.../.../db_table_backup.sql
```

Any it threw the help information, such as:

> 

mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.49, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 6.3
Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

> Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
> affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
> owners.

Any more tricks I could be overlooking?

Comment: I don't see any error message relating to a permission issue. We also don't know what's inside `db_table_backup.sql`, so I find it hard to advice. One thing which strikes me is the parameters  `dbname` and `db_table` . I didn't work so often with mysql, but why do you want to specify the name of the database and the name of a certain table, when you want to recreate everything from your backup? The SQL code should contain the necessary `CREATE` commands to perform this task.

Comment: BTW, why is this tagged _terminal_? I don't see how this is related to your terminal program, and you did not even mention, which terminal you are using, so you don't seem to consider this important either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that worked was slightly off [Giacomo1968’s answer](https://superuser.com/a/1101302/167207):

```
mysql -u root -p DBNAME < /home/MJV/.../.../db_table_backup.sql
```

If anyone can comment the difference between how these execute, I am sure people newer to Linux would appreciate the description.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your command is:

```
mysqldump -u root -p DBNAME db_table < /home/MJV/.../.../db_table_backup.sql
```

`mysqldump` is just a utility that will dump a MySQL database. You will never be able to import data into a MySQL database using `mysqldump`. Instead, you should just use the regular `mysql` command like this:

```
mysql -uroot -p[password] db_table </home/MJV/.../.../db_table_backup.sql
```

Of course replace `[password]` with your actual password but the overall syntax is what you are looking for.

Comment: Hi JakeGould,
I tried what you had suggested, and it threw the "help" information for Oracle MySQL, such as the commands. It doesn't go through? Any more advice?